# How do I update Python from 3.4.3 to 3.5?

Tags: python

I'm also using Jupyter and Anaconda, will it break/delete them or any python modules?

Comment: Take also a look here: http://superuser.com/q/241865/495631

Answer (score 17):

You can try to use this PPA to replace your current python with 3.5:

https://launchpad.net/~fkrull/+archive/ubuntu/deadsnakes

Usage instructions can be found on the linked webpage.

However, I would recommend installing python 3.5 parallel to 3.4 (under /opt for example).

For that you would need to install from source:

```
wget https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.5.1/Python-3.5.1.tar.xz
tar xfvJ Python-3.5.1.tar.xz
cd Python-3.5.1
./configure --prefix=/opt/python3.5
make
# To make idle3.5, you need tk's development to produce tkinter
sudo apt-get install tk8.6-dev
sudo make install
```

Your python 3.5 interpreter will be located in `/opt/python3.5/bin/python3.5`.
Your Integrated DeveLopment Environment is also found in
`/opt/python3.5/bin/idle3.5`.

To facilitate use you can symlink these files to a location on your `$PATH` like so:

```
sudo ln -s /opt/python3.5/bin/python3.5 /usr/local/bin/py3.5
sudo ln -s /opt/python3.5/bin/idle3.5 /usr/local/bin/idle3.5
```

After this, just typing `py3.5` from the command line will use python 3.5, while at the same time, python 3.4 will remain untouched, and will not  cause any "breakage" on your system. Also, `idle3.5` will bring up the 
IDLE editor with the python 3.5.1 shell.

Comment: What will happen to existing packages?

Comment: Using the second method... nothing. You will be able to keep them running just like before, since python 3.4 remains installed and the default interpreter.

Comment: `You can try to use this PPA to replace your current python with 3.5` - unfortunately this PPA doesn't include Python 3.5 (there are only obsolete versions) for Wily although there is Python 3.5 for Vivid, Trusty and Precise.

Comment: Python 3.5 was added for Vivid, Trusty and Precise just 5 days ago. Maybe something is delaying it for Wily, but it will eventually show up there (it always does).

Comment: how to install pip3 to python after installing python 3.5??

Comment: @TRomesh: You can follow the instructions [here](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/). But instead of running `python get-pip.py` run `/usr/local/bin/py3.5 get-pip.py`. This is assuming you have followed the instructions from the answer.